# WPF MultiColumn ComboBox with Header

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have (what seems to be) a fairly straight forward requirement for a combo box in WPF.

I'm needing a ComboBox with header which is bound to a ViewModel. I've found many other questions and answers on this topic, however none of them seems to work for my exact requirements.

Given the following (ninject) property:

```
  public List<OrderBatchVm> OrderBatches
  {
     get
     {
        return _orderBatches;
     }

     private set
     {
        Set(() => OrderBatches, ref _orderBatches, value);
     }
  }
```

And this ViewModel

```
public class OrderBatchVm
{                                                                                                                           
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public DateTime Time { get; set; }
   public string User { get; set; }
}
```

I've come up with the following from various other stack overflow questions

```
<ComboBox  Width="400" Height="22" ItemsSource="{DynamicResource items}"   VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <CompositeCollection x:Key="items">
            <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False">
                <Grid TextElement.FontWeight="Bold" Width="400">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.Children>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Name"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="User"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Date"/>
                    </Grid.Children>
                </Grid>
            </ComboBoxItem>
            <Separator/>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding OrderBatches}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>

        <DataTemplate DataType="viewModel:OrderBatchVm">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.Children>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding User}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Time}"/>
                </Grid.Children>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

The above produces a ComboBox with a header, however the data is not being bound to `CollectionContainer`.

After a fair bit of research into this approach, I think I understand what it's essentially trying to do, and the pitfalls of `CollectionContainer` , though I'm not sure if what I'm trying to achieve is possible, or how to achieve it.

### Update

The following does actually work, however it has no header which is my main requirement in this case:

```
<ComboBox  Width="400" Height="22" ItemsSource="{Binding OrderBatches}"   VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="viewModel:OrderBatchVm">
            <Grid  Width="400">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.Children>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding User}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Time}"/>
            </Grid.Children>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first approach doesn't display the collection since your DataContext seems not set correctly.
On the other hand, if it was set correctly, you wouldn't see the header, because the ComboBoxItem is set in the xaml, not belonging to the ItemsSource.
You can use viewmodel data (ItemsSource) OR a fix list of Xaml defined ComboBoxItems, NOT both.
In your case, I think you want to connect to the ItemsSource.

1)

I already impemeneted displaying a title in a dropdown using a Controltemplate similar to the MSDN example([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms752094%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).:

Simply place your title template inside the 'Popup'- definition, above the ScrollViewer (because you don't want the header to scroll!)

2) You also could manage it keeping your approach 2, simply enhancing your ItemTemplate to your needs (e.g. your viewmodel rule is: first collectionitem is always the header).